# firebase onAuthStateChanged() still returns user even after signing out?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, next-auth

i'm making a web app in nextjs with firebase, and i'm using nextauth.js lib for handling sessions, i have a page where i'm retrieving user data using onAuthStateChanged() function provided by firebase and it keeps returning user object even after sign out,

i have following nextauth.js config where i m calling firebase.auth().signout() on nextauth signout event callback,

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@auth/firebase-adapter";
import { firebase, firestoreDb } from "@/lib/firebase-admin.config";
import { firebaseAuth } from "@/lib/firebase-client.config";
import { signInWithCredential, signInWithEmailAndPassword, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export default NextAuth({
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        }),
        CredentialProvider({
            id:"email",
            name: "email",
            credentials: {
                username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "Email" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            authorize: async (credentials, req) => {
                const {email, password} = credentials;
                let firebaseCreads;
                try{
                    firebaseCreads = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        firebaseAuth, email, password)
                } catch(error){
                    throw new Error(
                        JSON.stringify({firebaseErrorCode: error.code}));
                };
                return {
                    user: firebaseCreads.user
                }
            },
        })
    ],
    adapter: FirestoreAdapter(firestoreDb),
    pages:{
        signIn: "/auth/signin",
    },
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    events:{
        async signOut({session, token}){
            // signing out user
            await firebaseAuth.signOut()
        })}
    },
    callbacks: {
        async signIn(user, account, profile) {
            if (user.account.provider === "google"){
                    const GoogleCreds = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(user.account.id_token)
                    await signInWithCredential(firebaseAuth, GoogleCreds)
            }
            return true;
        },
        async jwt({token, user, account, profile, session}){
            if (user){
                const firebaseUser = user.user;
                token.email = firebaseUser.email;
                token.uid = firebaseUser.uid;
                token.emailVerified = firebase.emailVerified;
            }
            return token
        },
        async session({session, token, user, trigger}){
            session.token = token;
            if (!token.emailVerified){
              firebaseAuth.currentUser.reload();
              session.token.emailVerified = firebaseAuth.currentUser.emailVerified;
            }
            return session
        }
    },
});
```

here is my page where i m using onAuthStateChanged to retrieve user,

```
export default function VerifyEmail(){
    useEffect(()=>{
        const unsubscribeEvent = onAuthStateChanged(firebaseAuth,(user)=>{
            if (user){                
                const onVerificationID = setInterval(function () {
                    user.reload();
                    if (user.emailVerified) {
                        console.log("Email Verified! will do something here");
                        clearInterval(onVerificationID);
                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        return ()=>{unsubcribeEvent()};
    },[])
    return(
        <>...</>
    )
}
```

firebase config

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_URL,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_GA_ID,
};

const app = !firebase.getApps().length? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : firebase.getApp();


export const firebaseClient = app;
export const firebaseAuth = getAuth(app);
```

i tried checking user object right after signing out and it worked as expected and returned null.

```js
events:{
   async signOut({session, token}){
       // signing out user
       firebaseAuth.signOut()
       .then(()=>{
          onAuthStateChanged(firebaseAuth,(user)=>{
            console.log(user); // null
          })}
       )
   }
},
```

somehow it signing in back again after navigating to that page,

i want it to log out user completely and delete current user state so the user retuned is null

update: just realised i was doing all that wrong, firebase sdk meant to be used in client side and i was using it in the server side that was the issue causing all that, i don't need to use nextauth.js at all, since firebase client sdk handle everything. i'm handling the session, signin, signups all firebase client sdk

Comment: `await firebaseAuth.signOut()` does not look like a Firebase API call that I know. If this is your own wrapper function, please include its code in the question or (preferably) reproduce the problem with only the minimum direct calls to the Firebase API

Comment: i apologies for that, i included my firebase config